# Getting started in Unit Testing as a group in these economic times

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

We have a group of a few developers and some business analysts. We as developers would like to start adding unit testing as part of our coding practices so that we can deliver maintainable and extensible code, especially since we will also be the ones supporting and enhancing the application in the future. But in this economic downturn we are struggling with the push to get started because we are challenged to just deliver solutions as fast as possible, with quality not being the top priority. What can we do or say to show that we will be able to deliver faster and with higher quality, as well as preparing for future enhancements.

Basically we just need to get over the learning curve of incorporating unit testing into our daily work, but we cannot do that now because it is viewed as an unnecessary overhead that would delay our projects that the business needs now.

We as developers want to provide the highest value to the business, especially quickly, but we know that we will also need to do this 6 months from now and we need to plan for that as well, and we believe that unit testing will help us greatly down the line.

**EDIT**
All awesome input, thank you. I personally know how to write unit test, but I don't have the experience in me to say whether or not that unit test is good. I have just ordered [Test Driven Development: By Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530) and will take the initiative to get the ball rolling on incorporating unit testing in our group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start unit testing the functions or classes when you create them. Begin with simple classes/functions that do not have external dependencies (DB, file system).

Share your progress inside the team. Count the number of tests and **display a big chart** showing your progress (unless the management/analysts are very hostile against unit testing).

Read about TDD: "[Test-Driven Development : by example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530)". Writing the tests first leads to code that can be easily tested. If you write the production code first, you may have hard time putting it under tests.

Answer (score 5):

You need to just start doing it, with or without permission.  In the end it will make you more productive and increase your code quality.  You can start small by including units for something critical and once you've shown the benefits, you're in.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to recommend the book
[Pragmatic Software Testing](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470127902.html)

The book [Pragmatic Unit Testing](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/utc2/pragmatic-unit-testing-in-c-with-nunit) is also a good book, although it focuses more on C# and NUnit, there are topics which are applicable language independent

Answer (score 2):

Just do it...

If it's part of your personal process for any new code, you'll at least have that covered.  You'll probably never get permission to add unit tests to cover all your code ever but you can at least be sure that no future changes undo work from a given point in time.

Think of it from the business side, why do you need to write code to prove the code you've already written is correct?  Why is it wrong?

Getting 100% coverage would be nice but take your time getting there and don't write tests for existing code that isn't currently wrong; write the tests as it breaks so you at least never undo something unintentionally.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to discuss it with management (though the situation you describe about it is far from ideal). It's like Design by Contract - I introduced it in previous code I worked in, just as part of the development process. Once it's in, and it works, trust me, noone will dare to remove it.

Unit testing can also be seen as a *part* of development. Hence, if you have "20 days" for developing features A, B and C, you can typically include unit tests in your estimations for development itself.

Making unit tests is surprisingly easy. Compared with multithreading problems or any sort of complex design, unit testing is very easy to grasp for any competent developer.

You can read good literature about it (you have dozens of tutorials online) in, say, half a day, and start doing your first tests in the afternoon.

Really - **just do it!**

Answer (score 1):

I know this may not be readily available to you, but I believe getting someone who's *test infected* on your team to show you the way is the easiest way to maintain productivity when introducing testing. Your people obviously need to know the concepts, which they can do by reading books or attending user groups. A test infected developer can show you how to do it in your practical everyday work with an absolute minimal loss in productivity whilst doing so. It wouldn't surprise me if your speed increased immediately, but I wouldn't make any claims of that sort. With test experience also comes knowledge of testable designs, which I think is key.

Comment: this definitely would be beneficial, but we currently don't have anyone like that in our group.